# how many quadrilaterals can be formed from $n$ points out of which $k$ points are collinear

Tags: combinatorics

how many quadrilaterals can be formed from $n$ points out of which $k$ points are collinear
, $n>k$

I was solving questions on permutations and combination, and I found this question which I have no idea, if how to proceed

Any help would be appreciable

Comment: Are "quadrilaterals" with one interior angle of 180 degrees allowed?  A triangle with a point somewhere in one side?

Comment: No! They are not allowed.

Comment: Did you try for small n,k

Comment: Do you mean that one set of $k$ points is collinear and all others are in general position, i.e. there is one line on which $k$ points lie and no other line on which more than $2$ points lie?

Comment: yes $k$ points are collinear, and all others are in general position

Answer (score 1):

First, assume that none of the points are collinear, and calculate how many ways to pick $4$ points from the $n$ points.

Then, subtract two categories of sets of $4$ points:

1. A set of $4$ points selected purely from the collinear set;
2. A set of $3$ points selected from the collinear set, and $1$ selected from the remaining general position points

Comment: can you please add an example to make it more clear